# Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'Partial '

Tags: typescript, nest.js

Создаю CRUD на nest.js использую **@nestjs/sequelize sequelize sequelize-typescript postgres**

котроллер:

```
@Put('/:id')
  async update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() data: UpdateGroupDto) {
    return this.groupsService.update(id, data);
  }
```

сервис:

```
async update(id: number, groupDto: UpdateGroupDto) {
  return await this.groupRepository.update(id, groupDto);
}
```

Не удается сделать update в сервисе, подсвечивает `update(id,`  с ошибкой -
`TS2559: Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'Partial '.`

Многие попытки решить ничем не увенчались.

По остальным методам вопросов нет, все работает.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L4136

Comment: Я видел доку и не понимал, наконец-то дошло. Теперь все работает. `async update(id: number, UpdateGroupDto: UpdateGroupDto) {
    return await this.groupRepository.update(UpdateGroupDto, {
      where: { id },
    });
  }`

Comment: Вопрос решен успешно.